# Getting buttonset data before submit button clicked?

Tags: jquery-ui

Gidday

Just learning the jquery UI, and have made some really good progress today, but have got stumped when figuring out how to get the ID of the selected button in a buttonset before the form is submitted.

I know how to make the AJAX POST work once I get the ID of the selected button.

How is the first part done?

Here's my jquery:

```
$( "#pi" ).buttonset();


    $( "#req1" ).dialog({           

        resizable: false,
        height:350,
        minWidth: 310,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Send request": function() {


                     //what goes here to retrieve the ID of the selected button?


                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

And my form...

```
<div id="req1" title="make your selection:">

<form>
<div id="pi">
    <input type="radio" id="p1" name="pi" /><label for="p1">3</label>
    <input type="radio" id="p2" name="pi" /><label for="p2">2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="p3" name="pi" /><label for="p3">1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="p4" name="pi" checked="checked" /><label for="p4">0</label>
    <input type="radio" id="p5" name="pi" /><label for="p5">1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="p6" name="pi" /><label for="p6">2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="p7" name="pi" /><label for="p7">3</label>
</div>
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var id = $('#pi input[name=pi]:checked').attr('id');
```